# How to run X-Wing Alliance on modern hardware?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, star-wars-x-wing-alliance

I'm trying to play **X-Wing Alliance** on my Windows XP with Core 2 Quad Q6600 and GeForce 8800GT, but I have to disable all graphics acceleration and I'm still getting major rendering glitches. Did anyone manage to properly configure this game (and/or the system) to run on modern hardware? If not, which virtual machine will most likely support this game?

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably need to play around with XWA Hacker, from a guy named Reimar.  You can [obtain it at the XWA Upgrade forums](http://www.xwaupgrade.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=9625&start=100#p137908).  The thread I linked to has to do with graphical glitches, which sounds like what you want.

I believe I had this working a few years ago on my machine, so I think it's possible.

Another path you could take is to try emulating it through DOSBox or virtualizing an older operating system.  One of those should work well for you.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little off topic, but yesterday I successfully started X-WING in a MS-DOS 6.22 virtual machine, set up with [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/de/products/desktop_virtualization/player/overview.html). At first I tried VirtualBox but EMM386 didn't work properly. With VMWare I had no problem to configure the OS to have enough memory to start the game. I assume X-Wing Alliance would run with VMWare too. Of course you may stumble across other issues than me. Let us know how you did it in the end.

Comment: Yep, most Virtual Machines will help you with running old games, I've used VirtualBox for running SimGolf and Theme Hospital - I think GOG distribute their copy of Theme Hospital with DOSBOX as their method of getting it to run on modern OSes as well...

Comment: This morning I installed and ran XWA on WinXP that was modified to run on Win7. I have no idea what the modification is, but I could play the game without obvious graphics issues. But I don't have such an up-to-date GPU.

Comment: Yes, I'd agree this is off topic. Even though X-Wing might have a lot of value history and story wise, from the perspective of non story random  clashes is largely rendered obsolete by X-Wing Alliance, and so this answer is a little bit noisy here. However the suggestion is fine.